# Enable modules inside vendor directory magento2

Tags: magento2

I upgraded the magento2 site manually and now modules that were installed via composer are disabled. How to enable those modules?

Updates: Installed modules again via composer.

Comment: try this command :- composer require <module-name>:<version>

Comment: And check this link :-- https://devdocs.magento.com/extensions/install/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable all modules use

```
php bin/magento module:enable
```

this will enable all modules installed on your project

If you want to enable specific module use

```
php bin/magento module:enable {Module_Name}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the module name in the registration.php file of the module,

To **enable** the module you need to run below command from Magento root directory,

```
php bin/magento module:enable [Module_Name]
```

For example, if you want to enable the **Magento_Catalog** module, Command should be as below

```
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_Catalog
```

To **disable** the module,

```
php bin/magento module:disable [Module_Name]
```

Also, You can check the module **status** using below command

```
php bin/magento module:status
```

Hope this information will work for you.

Comment: Already tried that and it doesn't work. I even added a reference manually in app/etc/config.php